# Pulling data from different tables into a single view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, controller

I recently started learning Ruby on Rails, and I am now in process of developing my first e-commerce web application. The application database has two tables at the moment: `products` and `variants`

`products` contains `id`, `name`, `description` etc. Each product may have several variants.

`variants` contains `id`, `product_id`, `price`, `image` etc. It also has a boolean field `default_var`, that determines the default variant that should be presented on the page, when the user first sees the product.

This is what the models look like:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :variants
end

class Variant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  scope :default, -> {where(dafault_var: 1)}
end
```

On the index page I want to be able to display the product list with an image, price and description next to it, so the information should be a combination of values from both tables.

In the index.erb view file, if I try to iterate through an array of products using the `each` method I have to use an index variable:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
```

I can't think of a way to access the variants controller methods through this local variable. What is the best way to get the data like `price` and `image` from the `variants` table? I would like to keep the Ruby code in the views to a minimum.

Controllers currently have the following code:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @products = Product.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
    #@products = Product.all
  end

...

class VariantsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @variants = @product.variants
  end
end
```

Comment: Variant controller methods? can you explain or show those?

Comment: Also do you wish to display all the variants of a product?

Comment: I guess I might be using the term methods incorrectly. As far as I understand all the logic of the program should go into controller, so what I really meant to ask was: Is there a way to avoid querying the database in the view directly, and rather have it nicely separated into the controller. For example, at the moment to access the fields of variants table I have this line in my view file: `<%  variant = Variant.find_by(product_id: product.id, default_var: 1) %>`
I only need to access the default variant on the index page.

Comment: Your first Rails project and you're trying to write an e-commerce site? Why not try to take on a bit smaller, less critical and complex, project to get your feet wet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have **one** default variant that has the image and price, I would do something like this

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def default_variant
    self.variants.find_by_default_var(1)
  end
end

<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <ul>
    <li><%= product.description %></li>
    <li><%= product.default_variant.price %></li>
    <li><%= image_tag(product.default_variant.image) %></li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Basically, you can get the `variants` from `product` directly

   ```
   <% @products.each do |product| %>
     <% product.variants.each do |variant| %>
       ...render your variant...
     <% end %>    
   <% end %>
   ```
2. This will cause a N+1 query problem later because each time you get `variants` from `product`, a query will be run. So we can do eager load for `@products` in `ProductsController`

   ```
   @products = Product.includes(:variants).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
   ```
3. `@variants` in `VariantsController` wasn't binding to `ProductsController` anyway, the instance variables in `VariantsController` will be used for variant views. You are in product views.

Answer (score 0):

The `ActiveRecord` way to access the `variants` is to use:

```
#app/views/products/index.html.erb
<% @products.each do |product| %>
   <% @product.variants.each do |variant| %>
      <%= variant.name %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Since you're using `has_many`, you could specify a `default` variant as an association, or even use an [ActiveRecord Association Extension](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions):

```
#app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :variants do
      def default 
        find_by default_var: true #-> @product.variants.default
      end
   end
   has_one  :default_variant, -> { find_by(default_var: true) }, class_name: "Variant", foreign_key: :product_id #-> @product.default_variant
end
```

This would allow you to call:

```
#app/views/products/index.html.erb
<% @products.each do |product| %>
   <%= product.default_variant.name %>
<% end %>
```

--

I don't know what effect this will have on `n+1` etc